# div is scrolling in chrome and firefox, not in safari

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a menu div on the left of my page (choptlogic.com), and in firefox and chrome it scrolls a bit, which I don't want it to do. In Safari, its perfect doesn't scroll at all. I've looked to see if any elements have excess padding that might be causing something, but the header class has an autoflow-y set to auto, so I'm a bit lost as to what might be causing this.
any help greatly appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: If you can show us the relevant HTML and CSS (perhaps in a fiddle) it would be a help.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got an element that is scrolling unnecessarily you can try to hide the overflow using CSS:

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At line 8995 add in your rule `overflow:hidden`

```
.header-inverse #page, .header-inverse .header, .header-inverse .header__inner-wrap 
{
  background-color: #09769f; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```